# Prove the convergence of binomial series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We already have the conclusion that
$$(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\ n\end{pmatrix}x^n,$$
$x\in(-1,1)$ when $\alpha\leq-1,$

$x\in(-1,1]$ when $-1<\alpha<0,$

$x\in(-1,1)$ when $\alpha>0.$

The first case is easy and the last is hard but I got it from by textbook. I have no idea about the case of $-1<\alpha<0$.

Comment: I think this question is homework.

Comment: Please include a question in the body of your question. And what does it mean for a situation to be "trial"?