# How to expand $(x+y)^{-n}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to expand $(x+y)^{-n}$ by binomial theorem, where $n$ is a positive integer? Is there any limitation for $x$ and $y$? If it can be expanded, how to compute the  coefficients? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446452/prove-the-convergence-of-binomial-series

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How about $x$ is a complex and $y$ is a real?

Answer (score 3):

It's not really the binomial theorem, but rather the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

$$ (x + y)^{-n} = x^{-n} (1 + y/x)^{-n} = x^{-n} \sum_{j=0}^\infty {{-n} \choose j} (y/x)^j$$
(convergent if $|y| < |x|$)

Comment: how about a combination of a complex and a real, like $[(\frac{v}{i+1}+1)^2+\frac{1}{2}]^{-n-2}$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $i$ is complex unit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
$$(x+y)^{-n}=\frac{1}{y^n}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+i-1}{i}(x/y)^i$$

Comment: Can you briefly explain how you get that?

Comment: Hi. $\binom{n+i-1}{i}$ is define of${{-n} \choose i}$

Comment: Is there any limitation of $x$ and $y$, real or complex?

Comment: The coefficient growth is polynomial (of degree $n-1$) with $i$, so the radius of convergence is$~1$; the formula is valid when $|x/y|<1$. When $|x/y|>1$ you can reverse the roles of $x,y$. When $|x/y|=1$ this does not give a convergent series in general.

Comment: @Farhad The upper of summation is $n$ or $\infty$?

Comment: Hi. yes, it is $\infty$. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has a singularity along the line $y = -x$. The expansion in terms of powers of $y$ and $x$ will differ depending on whether you are above or below this line.

No binomial theorem, but note that
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}
$$
whenever $|z| < 1$.

If we relabel $y = -w$, and look at $(x - w)^{-1}$, we get
$$
\frac{1}{x-w} = \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{x}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{x-w} = -\frac{1}{w}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{w}}
$$
which converge separately for $x > w$ and $w > x$ in each case (above and below the line x = w respectively).

But then $(x - w)^{-1}$ can be written as
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^{-n -1} w^n 
$$
and
$$
- \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n w^{-n-1} 
$$
in each region.

Now, 
$$
\partial_x^{n} (x - w)^{-1} = (-1)^{n} n! (x - w)^{-n-1}
$$
where I have written $\partial_x$ for the partial derivative with respect to $x$.

So
$$
(x - w)^{-n-1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \partial_x^n \left(\sum_{k > 0} x^{-k-1} w^k\right) \\
= \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (-k-1)(-k-2)\cdots (-k - n) x^{-k-1-n}w^k \\
= (-1)^n \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\begin{array}{c} k+n \\ k \end{array}\right) x^{-k-1-n}w^k \\
= x^{-n} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(\begin{array}{c} k+n \\ k \end{array}\right) x^{-k-1}w^k
$$
for the first case, and similarly,
$$
(x - w)^{-n-1} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} \partial_x^n \left(\sum_{k > 0} x^k w^{-k-1}\right) \\
= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\sum_{k \geq n} (k)(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)x^{k-n} w^{-k-1} \\
= (-1)^{n+1} \sum_{k \geq n} \left(\begin{array}{c} k \\ n \end{array}\right)x^{k-n} w^{-k-1}\\
= (-1)^{n+1}w^{-n}\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(\begin{array}{c} k+n \\ n \end{array}\right)x^k w^{-k-1}
$$
for the second.

Note that this works for any values $x, y$ $(= -w)$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How do you get the third equality in the first case? I do not think there is a $n!$. And also for the second case.

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to be more specific. What part of the third equality seems unusual? And the factor of $n!$ comes from using the $n$th derivative of $(x-w)^{-1}$ to compute $(x-w)^{-n-1}$.

Comment: But what is your definition of $\binom{k+n}{k}$?

Comment: Whoops! Yes, you're right. This is what I get for copying and pasting. I'm using the usual binomial coefficient. I edited it to fix it.

Comment: And the upper of the summation is $\infty$?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

See:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html

A limitation would be (x+y) <> 0